# Animate View Controller from Callout

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, callout

I have a set of annotations that each have a callout. I want the callout to animate in a new view controller page but keep the current on in the background. My first thought was to just create a normal push and have a clear background but I did not think that all the way through. Here is my current code which pushes to a new page.

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    InfoViewController  *objDetail = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];


    objDetail.pawpost = (PAWPost *)view.annotation;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDetail animated:YES];

}
```

Any suggestions how to animate in one view controller over the current one?

Comment: I think I don't know what you mean... What do you want ? To make a custom animation when you tapped the callout view and pushed to the infoViewController ?

Comment: Correct.. I would like the infoViewController to animate in and be only about 75% of the screen, so  that you are still able to see the viewController you just came from

Comment: If your are working on iOS 7, I suggest to you to create your own custom animation. Here is an article which explain how to do that (I tested it and it works): http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more